# Probability P(A intersect C)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Sample space $S =\{ 1,2,3,4\}$
Event $A = \{1,2\}$
$P(A) = 1/2$
Event $C = \{1,2,4\}$

$P(A \cap C) = ?$

I think since $2$ outcomes are common between Event $A$ and Event $C$.

(A ∩ C) = {1,2}
$P(A ∩ C) = {1,2}/{1,2,3,4} = 2/4 = 1/2.

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is $A \cap C$?

Comment: the answer is correct, but for totally the wrong reason. This has nothing to do with $\{12\}/\{1,2,3,4\}$, in fact that notation is meaningless. The point is just that since $A\subset C$ it follows that $A\cap C=A$.

Answer (score 0):

The event A intersecting with C is equivalent to the event A, as such the probability of A intersecting C equals the probability of A.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $A \subset C$. This means that whenever Event $A$ occurs, event $C$ will be occurring by default.

This implies that $P(A \cap C) = P(A)$

$\implies P(A \cap C) = 1/2$.

Comment: P(C | A)  = p(C ∩ A) / p(A)  = 1/2 / 1/2  = 1